Love or self respect
If you love you can't think of your likes and dislikes because it might not go with your partners likes or dislikes.  So how would we prioritize self first then partners ?

If the relationship involves you not thinking about your likes/dislikes in favor of those of your partner’s, that’s what I and others would classify as an unhealthy relationship.

I disagree with the premise. Our partners are imperfect, we are imperfect, love is imperfect, everything has Nth order effects. Life is about compromises and trade-offs.
